# using forever module for windows in nodejs

Tags: node.js, forever

I downloaded forever module from the following link

https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever

I extracted the zip file and placed it in my node_modules folder. and from my command prompt went into the node js path and gave

forever filename.js as instructed.But i received the error as below

```
C:\Users\290495\Desktop\newnode\Manoj\Node\nodejs>forever testing.js
'forever' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Don't know where i am goin wrong.Anyhelp will be much appreciated

Comment: install it with npm install -g like the doc says.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Forever needs to be installed globally. Install it with the `-g` flag i.e. `npm install forever -g`

Comment: i tried to install it using -g but still doesnt work: is this the syntax in cmd? : forever server.js

Comment: Vainglory07: forever start server.js

Answer (score 5):

There was a bug in forever (on windows). [Forever-win](https://www.npmjs.org/package/forever-win) is a windows compatible version for it.
Try below commands on windows command prompt, hopefully you should be able to run it successfully.

Install 'forever' and 'forever-win' globally

```
npm -g install forever
npm -g install forever-win
```

Start app using forever

```
cd <<project directory>>
forever start <<app.js>>
```

Comment: Just chiming in to say that, in my experience, forever now works well in Windows even without forever-win installed.

Comment: This still didn't work after trying the global install of `forever` and `forever-win`. Is there some manual steps to take? Adding it to path or something?

Answer (score 4):

Correct syntax is forever start app.js, but for some reason it doesn't work on Windows. No error message, but the application doesn't run.

Answer (score 3):

To build on top of [@richmb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/741808/richmb)'s answer. You can install it locally and then add it as a npm script in your package.json :

```
"scripts": {
    "forever" : "forever"
  },
```

Then , you can call it with `npm run forever`

Example :

`npm run forever start app.js`

`npm run forever list`

etc..

Comment: Like it, as platform independent

Answer (score 0):

To use it locally.

```
npm install forever
./node_modules/forever/bin/forever start <<app.js>>
```

Answer (score 0):

forever start -c node << server.js >>, specially in Windows without forever-win

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the npm folder path in the environmental variables.
As the forever command is present in that location.
"C:\Users<UserName>\AppData\Roaming\npm"

Answer (score 0):

For windows users, run these code below:

```bash
npm -g install forever

npm -g install forever-win
```

After that what you need to do is:

1. Go to environment variables
2. Edit the 'Path' inside 'System Variables'
3. Then input these:

> C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm
>
> C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\forever